# How to see what apps you have bought after doing a clean install

Tags: ipad

How can I get my apps back after a clean install if I bought all of them directly on my iDevice and never bothered to sync them to my computer?

Background: I lost all of my apps on my ipad when I updated (10/22/11) they were all gone.

Answer (score 5):

On your iPad log into the AppStore with the Apple ID you used to purchase the Apps. Then go to the Purchased tab and select them to be downloaded again.

[image: iPad Purchased Screen]

If you did not make a backup, which iTunes would have asked you to do before upgrading, you will lose all your data however.

You can also do this from iTunes by logging into the AppStore and clicking on Purchased and then selecting Apps under purchased:

[image: Purchased Link]

[image: Apps Option]

Answer (score 0):

- Open the App Store app
- Go to the 'Purchased' tab
- Download the ones you need again